# is there any way to calculate inequality of equation in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy, inequality

I was trying to use Sympy, but i can't pass two side inequality equation. 
for e.g -3 < 2 *x + 1 < 5.

Is there any way of getting inequality solution using python?

Comment: Well, `2x` will be invalid. What code did you try?

Comment: i have updated my question actually there was typo , -3 < 2 * x + 1 < 5.

Comment: See my answer below. The code works. I'm not sure what you mean by "but i can't pass two side inequality equation".

Comment: When I run type that inequality into python I get a boolean in return.  Are you looking for a range of x values that satisfy the inequality?

Comment: @IvanKelber Ooo, didn't think that's what he meant. I would have expected him to say that he's trying to *solve* the inequality.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's unclear.  I'm basing my question off the use of sympy.

Comment: I meant to say, both side of equation, here in the equation -3 and -5. But it seems, solution provided by alexis would work.  @ivanKelber, I looking for x values. If i solve it simply, Answer would be |x| = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula `-3 < 2*x + 1 < 5` abbreviates **two** inequalities into one:

```
-3 < 2*x + 1
     2*x + 1 < 5
```

In other words, it is a system of inequalities that you need to solve, using something like this:

```
solve_rational_inequalities([[
    ((-3, Poly(2*x + 1)), '<'),
    ((Poly(2*x + 1), 5),  '<')]])
```

Comment: From the documentation: `from sympy.solvers.inequalities import solve_rational_inequalities`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had but I briefly considered changing to `poly_inequality` (but munged the code)